# PHP Post параметры не приходят на сервер

Tags: php

PHP файл:

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo json_encode($id);
echo ' test';
?>
```

Запрос на сервер:
/test.php?id=1

Ответ с сервера:
null test

Где теряются отправленные данные, как найти?

Comment: Почитайте, пожалуйста, что такое GET-запросы и POST-запросы, и в чём их разница.

Comment: `json_encode` тут тоже не очень нужен

Comment: Здесь наверное проблема в сервере. любой отправленный параметр приезжает на сервер null

Comment: Также любые элементарные 100% примеры выдают мне в параметрах NULL

Comment: `$_REQUEST` в помощь, если не определились  с тем, как будут приходить данные.

Answer (score 2):

Параметр который передаётся в адресной строке после знака вопроса - GET параметр, следовательно в твоём случае сработает код:

```
<?php    
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    echo json_encode($id);
    echo ' test';
?>
```

Для того, чтобы отправить POST-запрос, самым простым вариантом будет использование формы HTML. Для этого создадим в той же папке что и test.php файл index.html *(ну или с любым другим названием)* в котором мы и напишем код нашей формы:

```
<html>
   <body>
       <!-- в форме пишем куда отослать запрос, и тип запроса (POST) -->
       <form action="test.php" method="POST">
           <!-- По name в текстовом поле мы получим его значение в .php файле -->
           <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Введите ID">
           <!-- кнопка отправит POST запрос в файл test.php -->
           <input type="submit" value="Отправить ID">
       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Поскольку мы создали текстовый input с name="id", после нажатия кнопки нас перекинет на файл который мы указали в action формы, и там значение этого поля мы сможем получить при помощи команды $_POST['id']. Для того чтобы запрос был именно POST мы указали это в method формы.

Теперь в .php файле сработает код с получением POST-параметра:

```
<?php    
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    echo $id;
    echo ' test';
?>
```

Удачи в освоении программирования! Если помог, можете поставить плюс и выбрать ответ как лучший

Comment: Я Postman использую. Это он пишет автоматом эту строку на запрос. Вряд ли он так косячит...

Comment: Сечас попробую.

Comment: Как мне понять, что параметр правильно на сервер приехал? Я хочу отправить в параметр POST например ААА и получить ААА назад. А назад приходит только null

Comment: @ДимаФилимонов, значит неправильно отправляешь. Попробуй, как написано в ответе.

Comment: @ДимаФилимонов в браузере вкладка Network, там показываются все запросы которые посылаются/принимаются, так же по клику на запрос можно увидеть что отправили вы, и что ответил сервер. Удобно для тестов.

Comment: Бывают ли какие-нибудь права в сервере на получение POST запросов?

Comment: @ДимаФилимонов может если проблемы с POST, попробовать передать в GET? /test.php?id=1 и в файле $_GET['id'] и посмотреть что будет. И убери "json_encode" перед выводом id

Comment: Я и гет и пост и копеечные примеры отправлял другие.

Comment: http://34.70.66.163/googledrive/android/market/test.php?id=1

Comment: "json_encode" так же убрал. Просто тогда не видно, что переменная пуста

Comment: <?php    
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo ($id);
echo ' test';
?>

Comment: @ДимаФилимонов напиши <?php $id = $_GET['id']; echo ($id); echo ' test'; ?> И что за редактор используешь? Не WebStorm/PHPStorm??

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Используйте

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Советую почитать разницу между [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php) и [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php)